# "Overscroll" a tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have this login form. This form is a grouped table view where the application title is the table header and the other things are group/table footer.

The problem is when the keyboard pops up it hides the login button. I tried to shrink the header view when the editing begins.

The problem with this is that this not animatable because you have to call [table refreshData] when the animation ended.

Is there a way to scroll the table view down "over scroll"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since table view is subclass of scroll view you chan change the inset of the scrollview and of the scroll bar. You just need to register as an observer of keyboard notification. Take a look here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html at the managing keyboard section